# Modular Monolith architecture gives MSDTC problem

Tags: c#, sql-server, modularity, msdtc

I am working on breaking up large spagetti-syle system written in .net/c# into smaller pieces. First step is to break up the app into components (c# classes in separate projects using their own storage) each working on it's own database or at minimum their own schema in MS SQL Server 2016 database. Each component uses their own connection string (different username).

When one component calls another (e.g. invoicing component needs to ask warehouse component for some data) we escalate immediately to MSDTC, which I am trying to avoid. I think the problem is multiple connection strings (transaction scope suppression does not help). However I want the components to use different connection strings and I think other components should not be aware what connection strings/databases etc. the other component is using.

Is there a way to have components with different connection strings and not escalate to MSDTC? Main thing I am trying to achieve is separation of concerns between modules..

EDIT: I am not trying to do cross-component transaction. I don't need transaction in this case.

Comment: `Modular Monolith` means nothing. Just like `microservices` it's a fashion term that can cover *anything*. Including the projects built over the last 20 years that used MSDTC/COM+. If you have multiple **connections** under *the same transaction* you *have* to escalate to a distributed transaction. If you want to avoid this, make sure you use a **single short-lived connection**. Which brings us to .... why do you want a transaction in the first place? If you use ORMs like EF you can rollback any changes simply by not calling `SaveChanges`.

Comment: If each component can fail independently though ... you have services, not components. Especially if each component has its own account. If everything runs on the same machine, `TransactionScope` isn't bad. At some point though you'll have to scale out. Or the distributed transaction starts causing delays. At this point you'll have to use one of the many distributed service techniques to handle consistency, eg idempotent operations, compensating transactions, sagas, queueing etc

Comment: `invoicing component needs to ask warehouse component for some data` that's one operation that *doesn't* need a distributed transaction. Your code is asking the warehouse component, it's not modifying its data. Even the Invoicing component won't need a transaction if it used disconnected datasets or an ORM, like all applications do for the last 20-25 years

Comment: I don't need transaction at all. I never said I need a transaction. I just want components to do their thing independently.

Comment: What's the point of the question then? DTC is used only when you use transactions covering two or more connections. Not connection strings but actual, open connections. Why are you using DTC at all?

Comment: The point of the question is to find out how to write two independent components in c# that can use each others functionality without being hindered by one of the components using a different connection with different connection string than the other without being promoted to DTC. This happens when one components calls a method of the other component that uses different connection string even. This happens even if no transactions are being used.

Comment: No it doesn't. DTC is only involved if you open a database connection while a TransactionScope is active, or if you *explicitly* use it. I'm using .NET Core on a Mac, with multiple connections to the same database. Needless to say, MSDTC isn't involved.

Comment: To put it another way, if what you say is true, a *lot* of people would have noticed 20 years ago. Neither .NET nor DTC are new. Post the code that causes the problem. Post a minimal example that can actually reproduce the issue. *Don't* just say that "opening a connection uses DTC" or post code that only opens a connection, because such code doesn't even use transactions

Comment: DTC means Distributed *Transaction* Coordinator. It's not involved at all if transactions aren't involved